# Closing a JFrame after a button is clicked Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Hello I am writing a sort of Menu for an encryption program I am writing.  I finished the core of it, and now i want to try to create a GUI for it.  Here is the code for the first Menu:

```
package matrix_with_GUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import java.awt.* ;

public class Main_Menu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
     private JButton action1 = new JButton ("");
     private JButton action2 = new JButton ("");
     private JPanel pane = new JPanel();
     private JLabel lbl;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main_Menu main = new Main_Menu();
}

public Main_Menu(){
    super();
    JPanel pane=new JPanel();
    setTitle ("Start Menu") ;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");

    setVisible(true);
    setSize (380, 260) ;
    setLocation (450, 200) ;
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;

    action1 = new JButton("Start");
    action2 = new JButton("Exit");
    lbl = new JLabel ("Welcome to the Matrix Encoder/Decoder!!!");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    add (lbl) ;
    add(action1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    action1.addActionListener (this);
    add(action2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    action2.addActionListener (this);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OptionsMenu x = new OptionsMenu();
    if (event.getSource() == action1)
    {
        System.exit(0);
        x.OptionsMenu();
    }
    else if(event.getSource() == action2){
      System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

}
When the Start Button is clicked, the new menu comes up all fine and good, but the first menu stays open.  Is there a way to close this first menu AND open the second menu with the first button click?  I'm very new to GUI so the simplest solution would be very helpful.  On a side note is there a simple way to move the Start button to the next line?  Thanks

Comment: Please check out: [the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: `System.exit(0);` Will cause the JVM to terminate.

Comment: 1) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 2) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Comment: `System.exit(0);` causes it to terminate, but it terminates without continuing to the next menu.  Unless i am putting this in the wrong place, this will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options: you can use a Window Listener, or you can use the dispose() method. To do the dispose() just type

```
* This is better to be used with subframes and 2nd level windows.*

this.dispose();
```

or check this link for using the window listener

[Closing JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892485/swing-programmatic-close-of-jframe)

Comment: no problem! Always glad to help :) I was given a gift from above, so I help all others :)

Comment: This code is good for a sub frame, but not for a main frame. Main frame should not be dispose they must be exit.

Comment: that is true, i had forgotten about that at the time of writing it

Answer (score 1):

In order to close the Main_Menu, you can just call its **[dispose](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29)** method:

```
this.dispose();
```

instead of calling `System.exit(0)`, which will terminate the JVM altogether.